# Disable current Button using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working on shopping cart and i need to check if specific article having specific size is out of stock. if out of stock of stock then i need to disable current "Add to cart" button instead of first or all buttons.
the response from controller is fine. and i am just getting one error.
it disable the first button instead of current button

```
  <a data-id="@item.ProductId" id="cartid" class="getid btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</a>


if (dataa.ProductId == selectedproduct && dataa.StockQty < 6)   
                    {
                        $("#cartid").attr('disabled', true);
                        $("#cartid").html("Sold Out");
                    }
                    if (dataa.ProductId == selectedproduct && dataa.StockQty >= 6)
                    {
                        $("#cartid").attr('disabled', false);
                        $("#cartid").html("Add to Cart");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An id attribute should be unique in your page. Means, if you have an element with id `cartid`, then no other element should have the same id. If you want to assign to multiple elements, you can use the `class` attribute.

Based on what you have described, I believe you have multiple buttons with the same `id="cartid"`. And that's why only the first element is getting modified!

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/p1sLt2cd/

So, what you have to do is, either use different `id` attributes, unique for each button. Or you can use `class` attribute to select all the buttons, iterate through them, check if they have enough quantity, then hide/display the button. For this purpose, you may have to store the quantity value in each button's `data` attribute to make it easier.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. actually i have list of button named "Add to cart" beacasue i have list of products and each product contain button "Add to cart"